# store only some data from table into a object

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
  <div id="contacts">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sort" data-sort="name">Name</th>
          <th class="sort" data-sort="age">Age</th>
          <th class="sort" data-sort="city">City</th>
          <th colspan="2">
            <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search contact" />
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="list">
        <tr>
          <td class="id" style="display:none;">1</td>
          <td class="name">Jonny</td>
          <td class="age">27</td>
          <td class="city">Stockholm</td>
          <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
          <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="id" style="display:none;">2</td>
          <td class="name">Jonas</td>
          <td class="age">-132</td>
          <td class="city">Berlin</td>
          <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
          <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="id" style="display:none;">3</td>
          <td class="name">Gustaf</td>
          <td class="age">-23</td>
          <td class="city">Sundsvall</td>
          <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
          <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="id" style="display:none;">4</td>
          <td class="name">Fredrik</td>
          <td class="age">26</td>
          <td class="city">Goteborg</td>
          <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
          <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button id="submitForm">submit</button>
</body>
```

js

```
function SendData(){

    var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'id', 'name', 'age', 'city' ]
    };

    var tableArray =[];

    $('#contacts tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        var lines = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
            return $(td).text();
        });
        // Here lines will contain an array of all td values for the current row:
        // like ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
        tableArray.push(lines);
    });

    console.log(tableArray);
}
```

i have some data contain in my table , there is "id, name, age, city, edit, and remove" but i only need the "id, name, age, city" to be store in my object , how do i do that ?and i also dont need to store the thead on top.

so i need to store class list "id, name, age, city" to my options object , how do i do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select only specific "td" tags from the "tr". For that selection to happen you can add an extra class to only those "td" as following.

```
<tr>
      <td class="id myData" style="display:none;">1</td>
      <td class="name myData">Jonny</td>
      <td class="age myData">27</td>
      <td class="city myData">Stockholm</td>
      <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
      <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can change you selector to include class "myData" also to the criteria. This will select "td" only with "myData" in their class attribute which will give you only data which you need.

```
$('#contacts tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var lines = $('td .myData', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
    // Here lines will contain an array of all td values for the current row:
    // like ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
    tableArray.push(lines);
});
```

Since you are selecting only "td" from "tr" so "th" will not be considered in this selection and you will get data only from the "td" which are having class "myData".

This should resolve your issue.